# need base64 encode/decode in c

Tags: c, function, base64

I need a function to encode base64 and a function to decode base64 string in c. I found http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c but the functions work on files, not strings, and add line breaks. I need one that simply encodes/decodes strings. Where can I find such a sourcecode?

Comment: Avaialable in the source for many FOSS projects, for example Apache.

Comment: Some more examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Get the functions from [libb64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

If you have openssl available to you (which most *nix distros seem to have out-of-the-box these days), it provides robust, well-tested base64 encoding/decoding out of the box. This site has a decent code sample: [Howto base64 decode with C/C++ and OpenSSL](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/122/howto-base64-decode-with-cc-and-openssl/)

Comment: Including a monster like OpenSSL for a 150 line solution, this is the sad way of programming these days

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to use Base64 encoding to build an encrypted email server, I decided to build my own implementation.

Currently, it's placed within a C++ class; but I wrote the encoding functions without using any c++ specific code, so you can copy and paste as you please.

This implementation is not approved by any organizations; but it should help you with learning how the algorithm works, while also giving you access to ***just*** base64 encoding. IE: no extra libraries get included.

https://github.com/AlexBestoso/Base64

Use as you please. The functions take chars, maps them to an integer via bit-wise operations, and then produces your result.

Currently, there's no newline or carriage return, which specified in the MIME implementation.

If you decide to use the code and find any bugs, let me know through github.