# How to decode base64 in C?

Tags: c, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I base64 encode (decode) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c)

Hello All,

Is there any way i can only decode the base64 string in C ?

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c

Answer (score 2):

I'm normally not one to say "just google it" when discussion brings out different things than searching, but googling for *base64 c* returns a bunch of implementations in the first page of results, such as http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c