# How to convert string to base64 ASCII Embedded in c

Tags: c, ascii, base64, encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I base64 encode (decode) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c)

I am trying to convert an int into an ASCII byte array and then encode the byte array as a base64 string.

I see a few posts on how to do this in C# and Java, but I want to do this in C. I'm doing this in windows, using MS Visual Studio.

Is there a function provided that can do this?

Here's the code that I would use in C# to do this:

```
var base64_string = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(my_integer));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of libraries available for that. One example is [libb64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/), which has a very permissive license.