# How to get PHP standard functions in C?

Tags: php, c

How can I call PHP functions from my C application?

**Example:**

```
include <php.h>

int main()
{
  return json_encode(""); // This is a PHP function coming from php.h
}
```

**Note:** PHP function collections is very managed and organized, i just want to have that logic in my C application, everything organized on-demand. Thats the beauty i found in PHP language.

Comment: AFAIK this won't be possible or really difficult and lead to many problems. And since the major part of PHP is written in C, there's nothing you can't do in C with a library or language functionnality. Why do you want to do that ? Why not use PHP directly ?

Comment: Without some crazy bit of hacking you shouldn't be able - PHP extension functions are defined in a very different way than in C. To use them you would need to push in zvals into the PHP functions, provide them with a PHPy-enough enviroment, a.s.o.

Comment: If you add an explanation of _why_ you want to do this (that is, what you're really trying to do), you'll get a much nicer set of answers. If the "why" is because you're used to php and need to write some C code, the answer is to learn C, or just use PHP.

Comment: There's a book called Extending and Embedding PHP that apparently deals with this. However, it was written in 2006 and could be out of date. Here's a [Slashdot review](http://books.slashdot.org/story/06/07/31/1416207/Extending-and-Embedding-PHP) and an [Amazon page](http://www.amazon.com/Extending-Embedding-PHP-Sara-Golemon/dp/067232704X) that may help.

Comment: You may also find [this blog post](http://phi.lv/?p=376) informative.

Comment: @jeremiahd: PHP function have a managed programming concept/standards like quick push to move fast and fury. In C language a common pattern does not exist (string/socket/etc etc not managed), everything requires to build from day 1. So if i can import PHP standard functions in pure C code i will use PHP functions only, without PHP interpreter involved.

Comment: all my life i ran implementing c functions in php, n u jst surprised me by asking this question, i m really interested in knowing your app demands that forces u to call php from inside of c

Comment: @Abhinav Singh: Its very organized language not only the shape but the beauty of functions collection, such as http://phpjs.org is doing using js. I am willing to have header file which can allow me to do it with pure C without involving PHP interpreter.

Comment: PHP is **not** "very managed and organized". There are **no** naming conventions nor parameter order conventions or any conventions of any sort. The PHP standard function library is an ugly mess.

Comment: I wish comments had downvote buttons

Comment: @Matti I agree with the statement, that PHP is a mess. With time it is becoming more and more organized I think, though. Unfortunately, it does not seem they will be fixing mistakes from the past...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since I also want my downvote today, I will try to answer to this question ;)

I don't know if what you're asking is possible. But I'm sure of some other things :

1. The result will be **really complicated**, **slow** and will lead to many **problems with dependencies** and portability.
2. You will get much better answer if you try to explain **why** you're asking this and what are the **goals** you want to achieve
3. The major part of PHP is implemented in C, so everything your doing in PHP can be done in C too. Concerning this, here's some reading about [**Turing Completeness**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).
4. Learning the C language instead of wanting to use some known PHP functions will open you **new perspectives** which will only **improve your coding skills**.
5. You should ask you if you really want / have to use C, or if it's better to use some **other higher level language**.
6. If you want to decode JSON messages in C, http://www.json.org/ lists plenty of **C implementation** of the standard you can use. For base64 decoding, see this [How do I base64 encode (decode) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c) for example.

Comment: @Marie I have only one answer for you : use PHP and not C ;) And BTW, like I already said, phpjs is a reimplementation in Javascript, it's a totally different thing.

Comment: @Marie: **None of the characters you have typed anywhere in this thread are making any sense**

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: This answer makes no sense at all, i wish there was a downvote of 50K at once. I think the the writer dont speak English or cant read. The question was asked having the functions of PHP to C as a collection, on-demand use it.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot. You can however ["extend" PHP using C](https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) and might be able to cook something up like this but it's not really useful. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Marie php.js is a reimplementation of some php functions in Javascript, this has nothing to do with what you're asking.

Comment: @Marie there's many C library which deals with JSON and base64 related stuff, have a look at my answer for some pointer. There is also plenty of function to work with sockets. Function like isset() don't make a lot of sense in C. You should ask yourself if C is the right language for what you're trying to achieve and, if it's the case, try to really learn it insteand of trying to use PHP functions.

Comment: @Marie then why are you doing C and not PHP ? There's also plenty of other languages you can use : Python, Java, etc

Comment: phpjs is a reimplementation of a subset of PHP in javascript - it's not like what you're asking here. "Managed" functions doesn't sound like a valid argument to me. The call semantics and general organisation is different for different languages. If that's a deal breaker for you, you should consider moving to the other language. If you want to write command line programs in PHP, you can use PHP as a regular interpreter outside your web server. The bottom line. Why do you want to do this? To CanSpice: Can you give me some pointers to where people have done (and used) this?

Answer (score 1):

Since C is faster than PHP, and PHP is written in C, I am thinking that trying to use PHP functions in C would make your program unnecessarily slow.  And I am pretty sure that it is impossible.

Comment: Right, so if you are trying to use php functions in a C program, and those functions have to go through an interpreter, they would be slower.  Why the heck did i get voted down?  Isn't this impossible?

Comment: @Corey it's not me :) I think 'pure' C-functions of PHP shouldn't go through the interpretor, only php-scripts should. But it's only guesses.

Comment: -1 because it's not impossible, people have embedded PHP in C in the past.

Comment: @CanSpice instead of downvoting everyone, provide some sources and exemple ;) And he said that he's *pretty* sure... BTW, the feasibility of something don't imply that it is a good idea.

Comment: @CanSpice, absolutely, ANSWER the question then, or maybe commenting is your way of answering without anyone being able to "vote" on your answer?

Comment: @Krtek: I don't know how to embed PHP in C, which is why I haven't answered. I do know that it's possible, and therefore the answers saying it's not possible are wrong, and downvoting wrong answers is kind of what downvoting is about.

Comment: @CanSpice, I'd say unless you can show us some code that does what the OP is asking, you're wrong in downvoting the answers that say it can't or shouldn't be done.

Comment: @CanSpice this answer isn't wrong, Corey said *pretty* sure ;) In a way, everything is possible in computer science, the question is just if you want to spend the time doing it and if you have something to gain. In this precise case, I really doubt there's anything positive in trying to call PHP functions in C.

Answer (score 0):

You could, and actually this is a project I have in mind.
What has to be done is to get the PHP SPL code and just rewrite it (clean it a little) to be used as a regular C library.
I'd like to do it some day.