# Portable way of printing hexa values with sprintf

Tags: c++, c, hex, portability, sign-extension

I've had some trouble with binary-to-(printable)hexa conversions. I've reached a functional (for my system) way of writing the code, but **I need to know if it is portable** on all systems (OS & hardware).

So this is my function (trying to construct a UUID from a piece of binary text):

```
int extractInfo( unsigned char * text )
{
    char h[3];
    int i;

    this->str.append( "urn:uuid:" );
    for( i = 56; i < 72; i++ )
    {
        ret = snprintf( h, 3, "%02x", text[i] );
        if( ret != 2 )
            return 1;
        this->str.append( h );
        if( i == 59 || i == 61 || i == 63 || i == 65 )
            this->str.append( "-" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understood that because of the **sign extension** my values are not printed well if I use **char** instead of **unsigned char** ([C++ read binary file and convert to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621893/c-read-binary-file-and-convert-to-hex)). Accepted and modified respectively.

But I've encountered more variants of doing this: [Conversion from binary file to hex in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292919/conversion-from-binary-file-to-hex-in-c), and I am really lost. In unwind's piece of code:

```
sprintf(hex, "%02x", (unsigned int) buffer[0] & 0xff);
```

I did not understood why, although the array is unsigned char (as defined in the original posted code, by the one who asked the question), a cast to an **unsigned int** is needed, and also a **bitwise AND** on the byte to be converted...

So, as I did not understood very well the sign-extension thing, can you tell me at least if the piece of code I wrote will work on all systems?

Comment: I don't *believe* the cast is technically needed, as the parameter will automatically be promoted anyway. The bit mask is also not needed. (Not an answer because I'm not 100% positive about the cast.)

Comment: If you're already using c++, why to use `snprintf()` at all? Any c++ code to output your stuff using a `std::ostream` will be portable whithout problems.

Comment: `unsigned char` will be promoted to `int` (unless `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`...), not `unsigned int`, and the `%x` format specifier says it needs an `unsigned int`.

Comment: You can use the hh length specifier: `snprintf( h, 3, "%02hhx", text[i] );`

Comment: If `buffer` is defined as `unsigned char buffer[N]` then neither the cast nor the bitwise AND with 0xff is necessary. If `buffer` is defined as `char buffer[N]` then you need to cast to `unsigned char` or you need to do the bitwise AND with 0xff; if you do both, it's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

since printf is not typesafe it expects for each formatting specifier a special sized argument.
thatswhy you have to cast your character argument to `unsigned int` if you use some formatting character that expects an int-sized type.

The `"%x"` specifier requires an unsigned int.