# Does strlen return same value for a binary and ascii data

Tags: c, string, char, ascii, strlen

Please find the below code snippet.

```
unsigned char bInput[20];
unsigned char cInput[20];
```

From a function, I get a binary data in `bInput` and I determined its length using `strlen(bInput)`.
I converted `bInput` which is in binary to ASCII and stored in `cInput` and printed its length. But both are different.

I am new to programming. Please guide regarding its behaviour.

Comment: No, strlen will not work for arbitrary non-string data.

Comment: `strlen` works by scanning bytes one at a time until it finds a zero byte (which is the conventional terminator for a character string).  Not going to work very well on binary data where an actual data byte might be zero.

Comment: What does "converted binary to ascii" mean?

Comment: You should ask yourself the question : "How do you define the length of binary data ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result wont be same for both cases.
Below is one sample scenario:
Null is valid UTF-8, it just doesn't work with C 'strings'.

```
   char temp[8];
   buf = "abcde\0f";
```

What we have here is a buffer of length 8, which contains these char values:

```
97 98 99 100 101 0 102 0
```

here,strlen(temp) is equal to 5 as per strlen design,however,The actual length of the buffer is eight.

Answer (score 3):

Function `strlen` returns the index of the first character in memory with a value of 0 (AKA `'\0'`), starting from the memory address indicated by the input argument passed to this function.

If you pass a memory address of "something else" other than a zero-terminated string of characters (which has been properly allocated at that memory address), then there's a fair chance that it will result with a memory-access violation (AKA *segmentation fault*).

Comment: @user2531564: If you choose to take back the V, at least do it for a reasonably better answer.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` counts each byte untill it reaches NULL character (`'\0'` that means value of a byte is zero). So if you are getting different length for binary and ascii characters means you need to check the below two points in your conversion logic,

- what you are doing if binary value is zero.
- whether you are converting any nonzero binary value to zero.