# Base64 . I cant decode image files

Tags: c

I have problem with my code. I got bmp image and encoded it in base64.Then i want it to decode , but my PC say: "Could not load image 'OUTPUT.PNG'".How can i fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


const unsigned char base64[] = {
    // ASCII table 
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64  
};

void deblock(const unsigned char *in, const unsigned char *base64, FILE * OutputFile, int len)
{
 if (base64[(unsigned char)in[0]] < 64  && base64[(unsigned char)in[1]] < 64)   
    fprintf(OutputFile, "%c",(base64[(unsigned char)in[0]] << 2 | base64[(unsigned char)in[1]] >> 4));
 if (base64[(unsigned char)in[1]] < 64  && base64[(unsigned char)in[2]] < 64)       
    fprintf(OutputFile, "%c",(base64[(unsigned char)in[1]] << 4 | base64[(unsigned char)in[2]] >> 2));
 if (base64[(unsigned char)in[2]] < 64  && base64[(unsigned char)in[3]] < 64)   
    fprintf(OutputFile, "%c", base64[(unsigned char)in[2]] << 6 | base64[(unsigned char)in[3]]);
}   

void decode (FILE *InputFile, FILE *OutputFile)
{

    int len = 0;
    unsigned char buffer[4] = "\0"; 

    while ((len = fread(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),4,InputFile)) > 0)
    {   
        deblock(buffer,base64,OutputFile,len);
    }   
}


int check_decode(FILE *file1, FILE *file2)
{
    int k = 0;

    fseek (file1, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (0 == ((ftell(file1)) % 4))
    {
        fseek(file1,0,SEEK_SET);
        decode(file1,file2);
    }
    else 
    {
        k = -1;
    }
    return k;
} 


int main() 
{
    FILE *file1 = NULL;
    FILE *file2 = NULL;
    if (NULL == (file1 = fopen("INPUT1.txt", "rb")))
    {   
        printf("Can't open INPUT file!");
        return -1;
    }
    if (NULL == (file2 = fopen("OUTPUT.png", "wb    ")))
    {
        printf("Can't create OUTPUT file");
        fclose(file1);
        return -1;
    }   
    if ( -1 == check_decode(file1, file2)       )
    {
        printf("Eto ne base64\n ");
        return -1;
    }
    assert(file1);
    assert(file2);
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}
```

I use this site to encode my image http://www.base64-image.de/step-2.php

Comment: All those `(unsigned char)` casts are useless. Elements of `in` are already have that type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26175293/992406    also http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c

Comment: You *encode* a BMP image with Base64 and expect it to *decode* as a PNG image? Perhaps your PC only said it cannot "load image 'OUTPUT.PNG'" because it is not a PNG at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I got bmp image and encoded it in base64.Then i want it to decode ,
>   but my PC say: "Could not load image 'OUTPUT.PNG'".How can i fix it?

Since you *got bmp image*, just create `OUTPUT.bmp` rather than `OUTPUT.png`.