# How do I convert encrypted raw binary data to/from a hexadecimal string in C?

Tags: gcc, encryption, hex

I am encrypting a string using the crypto libraries in C (using gcc in Linux). Here is what I would do:

```
 ien = encrypt ((unsigned char*)passwd, strlen(passwd), (unsigned char*)cypher_key, (unsigned char*)cypher_salt, cypher_text);
```

Now if I were to print out the contents of cypher_text, it would be all garbled. I need this to be saved to a text file (it will be hashed with other things so as to be obfuscated eventually). This right now is an experiment. I need to convert this raw binary data into a hexadecimal string that is readable in any text editor.

Then, I need to convert that hexadecimal string back into raw binary so I can do this and get the original text:

```
decrypt(cypher_text, ien, (unsigned char*)cypher_key, (unsigned char*)cypher_salt, (unsigned char*)passwd);
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how I could accomplish this?

**UPDATE** A suggested link about printing hex in C isn't exactly what I am after. I am taking direct *unprintable* data put out by the encrypt function (not hexadecimal values in an array) and trying to convert it into a string of hexadecimal numbers and be able to convert that hex string back into it's original binary form. I hope that helps clear up some of what I'm trying to do.

I'm going to look into the idea of using base64 encoding but I can't have headers, etc. in the encoding. I'll need just a straight string.

Comment: Typically you'd use something like [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to encode/decode binary data as text - it's very simple and there are no doubt open source libraries out there that you could use, in order to avoid "re-inventing the wheel".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/342409/1362568

Comment: @ArtjomB. That link they discussed something that was already in hex. What I'm trying to convert is something that is unprintable.

Comment: @RavenLX You're right. Turns out, it is a little hard to find a generic binary `char[]` to hex `char[]` conversion duplicate target question.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the heading at the top of my question that says "This question may already have an answer here:
Printing hexadecimal characters in C 7 answers"? That link doesn't answer the question.