# Storing crypted data with libconfig

Tags: c++, c, linux, libconfig

I'm using the libconfig to create an configuration file and one of  the fields is a content of a encrypted file. The problem occurs because in the file have some escapes characters that causes a partial storing of the content. What is the best way to store this data to avoid accidental escapes caracter ? Convert to unicode?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Encode your encrypted content with `base64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either **URL encoding**, where each non-ASCII character is encoded as a `%` character followed by two hex digits, or you case use **base64 encoding**, where each set of 3 bytes is encoded to 4 ASCII characters (3x8 bits -> 4x6 bits).

For example, if you have the following bytes:

```
00 01 41 31 80 FE
```

You can URL encode it as follows:

```
%00%01A1%80%FE
```

Or you can base64 encode it like this, with 0-25 = A-Z, 26-51 = a-z, 52-62 = 0-9, 62 = ., 63 = /:

```
(00000000 00000001 01000001) (00110001 10000000 11111110) -->
(000000 000000 000101 000001) (001100 011000 000011 111110) 

AAJBNYD.
```

Comment: In my case using an algoritm to convert to base64 solved the question

Answer (score 2):

The standard for encoding binary data in text used to be uuencode and is now base64. Both use same paradigm: a byte uses 8bits, so 3 bytes use 24 bits or 4 6 bits characters.

uuencode just used the 6 bits with an offset of 32 (ascii code for space), so characters are in range 32-96 => all in printable ascii range, but including space and possibly other characters that could have special meanings

base64 choosed these 64 characters to represent values from 0 to 63 (no `=:;,'"\*(){}[]` that could have special meaning...):

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
```

and the equal sign(`=`) being a place holder for empty positions and the end of an encoded string to ensure that the encoded string length is a multiple of 4.

Unfortunately, neither the C nor C++ standard library offer functions for uuencode not base 64 conversions, but you can find nice implementations around, with many pointers in this other SO answer: [How do I base64 encode (decode) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c)