# C++ Base64 Image encoding of already loaded image

Tags: c++, image, base64, jpeg

I make an image in memory and then I need the resulting base64 string encoding; actually I use the code in [How do I base64 encode (decode) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c) but it works on image in jpg format; so, I need to do the intermediate step to save my image (that is in memory in RGB format) so that I have it in jpeg, then reload it in a stream and finally I can use CBase64

```
        save_jpeg("temp.jpg");
        std::ifstream iss("temp.jpg",std::ios::binary);
        CBase64 cb;
        std::ostringstream oss;
        cb.Encode(iss,oss);
        return oss.str();
```

I would avoiding save the jpeg format on disk and then reloading it; for me is not important the format of the resulting cbase64 (jpeg, bmp, etc.) is just important that coping it in an HTML I can view it.

Comment: base64 is not format aware, so you don't need jpeg format to use it.

Comment: yes, but the code I use seems to require that image si coded i jpeg format