# Convert unsigned char array to base64 string

Tags: javascript, c++, activex

I have an unsigned char array that represent an image, and I want to show it in a web page.

I get the array from ActiveX Control, and I want to show it in my web page using JavaScript, so I have to convert it to "base64 string", so my question is

how to convert unsigned char array to base64 string in c++?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Apple has published an open source Base64 encode/decoder. I recall having this compile with no issue on a Windows project once.  Source [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-452/CommonUtilitiesLib/base64.c).  Header [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-452/CommonUtilitiesLib/base64.h).

For example:

```
unsigned char* array = <your data>;
int len = <number of bytes in "array">

int max_encoded_length = Base64encode_len(len);
char* encoded = new char[max_encoded_length];

int result = Base64encode(encoded, (const char *)array, len);

// encoded is now a null terminated b64 string
// "result" is the length of the string *including* the null terminator
// don't forget to invoke "delete [] encoded" when done
```