# C: Read Binary and Write as encoded text

Tags: c, jar, software-distribution

I wish to read a jar in binary mode and write the binary as string(encoded if need be) to a file.
This string would be included in code to be read and converted back into binary and written as a jar file.

I'm trying to replicate what get-pip.py has done to distribute pip.

What would be the best way to do this in C?

Comment: perhaps you should investigate base64: https://stackoverflow.com/q/342409/1212725

Comment: Indeed. Base64 is the standard way to encode arbitrary binary data as a sequence of printable characters.

Comment: @bruceg thanks for the link, there is an answer there that compares many implementations and shows the best encoding and the best decoding implementation. Can I use the best of both or do I have to stick a complete implementation?

Comment: @SamThomas base64 is a standard. you can use the encoder from one implementation, and the decoder from another. Back in the dark ages when I had to do it myself, I always used a simple table driven approach.

Comment: @bruceg Cool Thanks :D

Comment: @bruceg Can you submit an answer? I'll accept it and lets close this :D

Comment: @SamThomas here's the consolidated information in the answer below.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base64 encoding for this.  Base64 is a standard, and you can use the encoder from one implementation, and the decoder from another, and you'd get back the original string on the other side.  The typical straightforward implementation is a table driven one, as in this answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782480/1212725