# C++: Convert base64 string into Image

Tags: c++, image

is there some way to convert a base64 string into an image; in Visual C++? I got an image as a result of getting the image from an url, encoded as a base64 so, I need to get it back.

I'm really lost in this matter; I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

So far I've been digging about GDI+ but I don't know if it is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746855/how-can-i-create-an-image-in-gdi-from-a-base64-encoded-string-in-c

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link; it helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert into bytes, convert bytes into bitmap, (optional) bitblt bitmap onto window.

[How do I base64 encode (decode) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c)

[How can I create an Image in GDI+ from a Base64-Encoded string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746855/how-can-i-create-an-image-in-gdi-from-a-base64-encoded-string-in-c)

You need to know what type of image the resulting bytes are. Then you need to find an algorithm that can understand that, or just save the bytes as a file type (if it is already built with header info and everything).

If it's just a bitmap (like a MFC bitmap), you'll need a way to convert that into an image, if you intend to save it. If you just intend to display it and it's already a bitmap, then just use the GDI methods.

Comment: Hello, I followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746855/how-can-i-create-an-image-in-gdi-from-a-base64-encoded-string-in-c and worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Boost is a great set of libraries when it comes C++ and it's documentation can be found [here](https://www.boost.org/).

So we have a encode and decode supported by [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/boost/beast/core/detail/base64.hpp).

A more detailed implementation of Boost Base64 encode-decode can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349697/decode-base64-string-using-boost).

Another useful library is of Microsoft CPPRESTSDK, also known as [Casablanca](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk) project. Under this they have defined a [utility::conversion](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility_1_1conversions.html) namespace which deals with all different type of encoding-decoding which one can come across while developing an API. Among this [from_base64 (const utility::string_t &str)](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility_1_1conversions.html#aff2e479f0fb5a278935648fe8a0d4abb), which can be used to decode the given base64 string to a byte array.