# Bitmap.FromFile not finding the file

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2013, bitmap, gdi+

I am trying to load a picture (.bmp or .jpg) with this code:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
Gdiplus::Bitmap* image = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(fileName, false);
if (image == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Picture not found" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

I always get "Picture not found".
I 've tried the following:

```
TCHAR* fileName = L"background.bmp";
TCHAR* fileName = L"C:\\background.bmp";
```

The picture is on C: and in the project folder.
Where should I save the image, so that it can be found?
Or am I doing something essential wrong or am I missing something?
I am using Visual Studio2013 and a Win32 console application (native C++).
Thank you for your help

Comment: `TCHAR* fileName = L"C:\\background.bmp";` means look at the root folder of c:

Comment: ***The picture is on C: and in the project folder. Where should I save the image, so that it can be found?*** The default folder is normally the same folder as the one containing the solution `.sln` file however you can change that in the Debugger settings of your project.

Comment: Perhaps this question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163372/bitmapfromfile-returning-null-on-x86