# How to convert from 'const char [9]' to 'const unsigned char *'

Tags: c++

I'm trying the code [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180949/2723500):

```
std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) {
}
```

And pass: `base64_encode("mystring", 8)`.

It shows a type conversion error:

> error C2664: 'base64_encode' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [9]' to 'const unsigned char *

Comment: I think your main issue is `unsigned char const*` try just having it be a `char*`

Comment: Your string literal is an array of char, not an array of unsigned char. You'll either need to cast it, or use an array of unsigned char as your input.

Comment: I don't understand why it was a "const" in the first place. But it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this post and wanted to clarify a bit for anyone else trying to base64 encode a string. The code referred to by the original poster comes from the web page: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html. If you go to the author's page and look under the "The test file" section you will see exactly how the author recommends the code to be used.

```
const std::string s = "test string" ;
std::string encoded = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s.c_str()), s.length());
```

I tried it in my program and it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have string literals using `unsigned char`s. The easiest way to create a sequence of `unsigned char`s from a string literal is probably

```
char const* literal = "hello";
std::vector<unsigned char> ustr(literal, literal + std::strlen(literal));
unsigned char const* ustrptr = ustr.data();
```

Obviously, the logic could be encapsulated into a suitable function calling `base64_encode()`.

The alternative is to just `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>("hello")` but I'm personally not a big fan of this approach.

Comment: I think  Zack Newsham's solution is more elegant. C++ can look a bity ugly, because of stuff like this: "std::vector<unsigned char> ustr(literal, literal + std::strlen(literal));
unsigned char const* ustrptr = ustr.data();"  Why don't you like: reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>("hello")?

Comment: I think `unsigned char x[] = "hello";` is also possible, see [dcl.init.string]/1.

Comment: Other than the use of `reinterpret_cast`, what about the casting solution are you not a fan of? Seems wasteful to copy the string in order to do what is essentially a cast?

Comment: Another cast-style solution would be `using uchar_arr = unsigned char const[]; bae64_encode(uchar_arr{"hello"});`.

Comment: @Troy: The behavior of `reinterpret_cast<...>()` is generally implementation defined. Since my code is meant to platforms I don't even know, using anything which is implementation defined is problematic. While the conversion approach may introduce some overhead, it is portable.

Comment: What do I do if I want to base64 encode a std::string instead?

Comment: @user2723500: I'd do roughly the same: `std::vector<unsigned char> ustr(str.begin(), str.end());`