# Convert base64 decoded string to unsigned char[32]

Tags: c++, type-conversion, base64, ed25519-donna

I'm using [ed25519-donna](https://github.com/floodyberry/ed25519-donna) to digitally sign.

The keys are `unsigned char[32]`, and the signatures are `unsigned char[64]`.

I've found [this base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180949/1382306), but it only decodes into `string`.

I've found and tried many techniques but am still unsure of how to convert.

How can a base64 decoded `string` be converted to an `unsigned char[32]`?

Comment: it doesn't need to be converted. its base already is `unsigned char*`, and by design usable as `unsigned char const*`. You have no issue just passing `var` as the `unsigned char const*` parameter, where `var` is declared as `unsigned char var[32];` and properly loaded with your binary key/signature.

Comment: Ah. That makes considerably more sense. There are a plethora of base64 encode/decode implementations out there already. Usually your crypto API has one (Microsoft CryptoAPI and OpenSSL certainly do). If you're looking for a reasonable implementation [this may work for you](http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c). It isn't terribly hard to simply feed it data from a vector or flat array rather than a file, and its pretty solid.

Comment: If they are `std::string` you should simply be able to use any base64 decode algorithm passing the string `c_str()` and `length()` respectively. Ultimately its all string-to-bytes or bytes-to-string in the end.

Comment: @WhozCraig I apologize, but I still cannot figure this out.  I tried `strncpy` and many others.  I just can't get it.  Would you mind posting a quick example of how to convert a `string` to a `unsigned char[32]` or `unsigned char[64]? Thank you so very very much in advance!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gracchus:

Here it is.  Enjoy!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct BASE64_DEC_TABLE {
    signed char n[256];

    BASE64_DEC_TABLE() {
        for(int i=0; i<256; ++i)    n[i] = -1;
        for(unsigned char i='0'; i<='9'; ++i) n[i] = 52+i-'0';
        for(unsigned char i='A'; i<='Z'; ++i) n[i] = i-'A';
        for(unsigned char i='a'; i<='z'; ++i) n[i] = 26+i-'a';
        n['+'] = 62;
        n['/'] = 63;
    }
    int operator [] (unsigned char i) const { return n[i]; }
};

size_t Base64Decode(const std::string& source, void* pdest, size_t dest_size) {
    static const BASE64_DEC_TABLE b64table;
    if(!dest_size) return 0;
    const size_t len = source.length();
    int bc=0, a=0;
    char* const pstart = static_cast<char*>(pdest);
    char* pd = pstart;
    char* const pend = pd + dest_size;
    for(size_t i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        const int n = b64table[source[i]];
        if(n == -1) continue;
        a |= (n & 63) << (18 - bc);
        if((bc += 6) > 18) {
            *pd = a >> 16; if(++pd >= pend) return pd - pstart;
            *pd = a >> 8;  if(++pd >= pend) return pd - pstart;
            *pd = a;       if(++pd >= pend) return pd - pstart;
            bc = a = 0;
    }    }
    if(bc >= 8) {
        *pd = a >> 16; if(++pd >= pend) return pd - pstart;
        if(bc >= 16) *(pd++) = a >> 8;
    }
    return pd - pstart;
}

int main() {
    std::string base64_string = "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8=";
    unsigned char decoded_data[32] = {0};

    Base64Decode(base64_string, decoded_data, sizeof(decoded_data));

    for(auto b : decoded_data) {
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(b) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient solution for base64 decoding is using Boost C++ library. Base64 decoding function using Boost C++ library can be found at : [attempt to decode a value not in base64 char set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680998/attempt-to-decode-a-value-not-in-base64-char-set])

Answer (score 0):

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c) talks about decoding a base64 string to an `unsigned char` (`uint8_t`) array. There's a lot there, and it also seems someone took the code there and posted it [here](https://www.mycplus.com/source-code/c-source-code/base64-encode-decode/) (or vice-verca.)

After looking at all these threads and options (as mentioned above there's a lot of tools out there for this), I used [the open source one from Apple's open source libraries](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ChatServer/ChatServer-37.1/jabberd-src/jabberd/lib/base64.c.auto.html). There are many issues with the various code snippets posted in the other SO post that dissuaded me so I decided to stick with the one from Apple since it looked quite clean and has good provenance. I tested it out with a some base64 strings I converted with this [online tool](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en) and it was all correct.

You need to replace `#include "lib.h"` with:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

And then make a quick `base64.h` to include (the one I found on Apple's open source didn't seem to match)

```
#ifndef _BASE64_H_
#define _BASE64_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

size_t base64_decode(char *source, unsigned char *target, size_t targetlen);
int base64_encode(unsigned char *source, size_t sourcelen, char *target, size_t targetlen);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //_BASE64_H_
```