# Why isn't this base64 decode/encode function working properly?

Tags: c++, base64

I am using the base64 function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180949/6463343) to try and run a simple program. I want to convert binary to base64 using this code:

```
int x = 1;
std::string data = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>((void *)&x), 4);
std::string out = base64_decode(data);
int y = reinterpret_cast<int>(out.data());
```

The encode function is called, and generates this string `"AQAAAA=="`. From my understanding, this would should convert to `01 00 00 0` if decoded and converted to bytes (I actually don't understand why it's 7 bytes). When the decode function is called, I expect `01 00 00 00`, which would then be reinterpret_castable back into the integer 1, but rather I get `"\001\000\000"`, which is not what I expect. I tried increasing the second parameter of the encode function, funnily, it gives me the proper answer of `"\001\000\000\000"` after decode.

Comment: An [mcve] would allow us to reproduce your problem...

Comment: I figured my code example meets the criteria for that. Let me know if I can change it in any way.

Comment: Can I copy, paste, compile, run, see your results? No. Anyway, I am *very much* doubting your `reinterpret_cast<>`s are a good idea...

Comment: Actually, after pasting the linked implementation and your code into a whole, I get this: `error: cast from 'const char *' to 'int' loses precision`. So your code doesn't compile...

Comment: Ok, right. However, I'm trying to balance minimal and complete.

Comment: It compiles on my system.

Comment: The point in "complete" is that, to check if any suggestion *actually* works, *every potential answer* includes cobbling the parts together to something that compiles (which your code doesn't, see above). That's why we're asking for questions that *don't* require that kind of footwork for an answer. -- The combination of `reinterpret_cast<>` and "works on *my* system" should ring all kinds of bells. ;-)

Comment: I'd like to mention again that the code above, copied directly, compiles on my system. I'll make an effort to include a more complete code that makes it easier for one to test next time.

Comment: The underlying idea is that attempting to achieve a *minimal* example is important debug work, which quite frequently reveals the problem before you even ask. For example, you'd rather avoid pasting the full base64 implementation. Can you "mock" it, and still get the kind of surprising result? This makes you look at your intermediate results, and you can either pinpoint a specific behaviour of the base64 implementation, or an issue with your casts for example. You take variables out of the equation, making the example simpler, until either the problem is obvious or the question more focussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180949/104458) for base64, I suspect the following will work:

```
int x = 1;
std::string data = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&x), 4);
std::string out = base64_decode(data);
int y= *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(out.c_str()));
```

On whatever side is doing the decode logic, it should probably validate that `out.size() == sizeof(int)` before doing this conversion.

Comment: That works, just need a const_cast<char *> in there. Thank you.

Comment: I thought y = reinterpret_cast<int>(out.c_str()) would work the same as memcpy(&y, out.c_str(), 4), but it turns out memcpy gives the correct result while the first gives a garbled result.