# when const pointer is used as parameter of function

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments, constants

entire code is below link.
[base64 decode snippet in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180947/base64-decode-snippet-in-c)
I have a question about const pointer in above link code.

### main

```
std::vector<BYTE> myData;
...
std::string encodedData = base64_encode(&myData[0], myData.size());
```

### base64_encode

```
std::string base64_encode(BYTE const* buf, unsigned int bufLen) {
  std::string ret;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  BYTE char_array_3[3];
  BYTE char_array_4[4];

  while (bufLen--) {
    char_array_3[i++] = *(buf++);
    if (i == 3) {
```

parameter is BYTE const* buf, not const BYTE* buf.

when const BYTE* buf is used as parameter,
const is for BYTE, so pointer can be changed but the value of buffer can not be changed.

when  BYTE const* buf is used, const is for pointer variable, so value can be changed but address can not be changed.

in above code, 
buf pointer is const, but buf++ is possible?

and why BYTE const* buf is used instead of const BYTE* buf?

thanks

Comment: Loosely related: Here'a neat tool for helping figure out what "C gibberish" really means: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: The rule is that `const` binds to the thing to its immediate *left*... unless `const` is the first thing, in which case (as an exception to the general rule) it binds to the thing to its immediate *right*.

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly, `const BYTE*` and `BYTE const*` [are equivalent to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const?rq=1).  Both are pointers-to-const.

To make the pointer itself const, the formulation is `BYTE *const`.  A const pointer-to-const would be `BYTE const *const` or `const BYTE *const`.

I cannot speculate as to why the authors of this function chose the `BYTE const*` version instead of the much more popular `const BYTE*`.

Comment: Why do you think `const BYTE*` is more popular?

Comment: In `BYTE const * buf`, the `const` applies to the item before  (`BYTE` is `const`). With `BYTE * const buf`  the `const` item, the pointer , is also before the `const` . This makes `const BYTE * buf` the outlier.

Comment: thank you 
I coufused

BYTE const * and const BYTE * are same.

I confused with BYTE* const buf and const BYTE* buf.
thanks a lot.

Comment: @eerorika:  I made that observation based on my experience reading C++.

Comment: It's much more common in the code I've found `const T` than `T const` because it's also more human readable. You'd usually say "a constant string" and not a "a string constant" although both mean the same. Saying "a string constant pointer" is confusing (both in C and in some human languages, at least in spanish adjectives could be before or after a noun) imho.