# C++ OPENSSL - How to convert OPENSSL output to a readable text and store it to a variable (if possible)

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I have the **working** code below using **OPENSSL AES 256 CBC** to encrypt/decrypt.
It is working but I am missing something really important that is to CONVERT the Encryption result to readable text and STORE it to a STRING variable if possible (for later use).
For example, I need to see something like this: UkV8ecEWh+b1Dz0ZdwMzFVFieCI5Ps3fxYrfqAoPmOY=
Trying hard to find how to do that and what format OPENSSL is throwing out from Encryption process. (binary format ??) See image attached.

*ps. Don't worry about the hashes below. They are not in production.*

Thanks in Advance!!

**Here is my code so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>



using namespace std;


// HEX PRINT
static void hex_print(const void* pv, size_t len)
{
   const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)pv;
   if (NULL == pv)
       printf("NULL");
   else
   {
       size_t i = 0;
       for (; i < len; ++i)
           printf("%02X ", *p++);
   }
   printf("\n");
}


// Starting MAIN function
int main()
{
   int keylength = 256;
   unsigned char aes_key[] =  "1Tb2lYkqstqbh9lPAbeWpQOs3seHk6cX";

   // Message we want to encrypt
   unsigned char aes_input[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   
   size_t inputslength = sizeof(aes_input)-1;   // -1 because we don't want to encrypt the \0 character
   
   // initialization vector  IV - same for Encryption and Decryption
   unsigned char iv_enc[] =  "JxebB512Gl3brfx4" ;
   unsigned char iv_dec[] =  "JxebB512Gl3brfx4" ;
   
   // buffers for encryption and decryption
   const size_t encslength = inputslength ;
   unsigned char enc_out[257];
   unsigned char dec_out[257];
   memset(enc_out, 0, sizeof(enc_out));
   memset(dec_out, 0, sizeof(dec_out));

   //Encryption START
   AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
   AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, keylength, &enc_key);
   AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, inputslength, &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);
   
   //Decryption START
   AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, keylength, &dec_key);
   AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out, dec_out, encslength, &dec_key, iv_dec, AES_DECRYPT);
       
   // Printing Results
   printf("original: \t");
   hex_print(aes_input, sizeof(aes_input));
   cout << aes_input << endl;

   printf("encrypted: \t");
   hex_print(enc_out, sizeof(enc_out));
   cout << enc_out << endl;
   

   printf("decrypt: \t");
   hex_print(dec_out, sizeof(dec_out));
   cout << dec_out << endl;
   
   
 
   return 0;
}
```

[Image of the Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zbj9.png)

Comment: Have you heard of [base 64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

Comment: OpenSSL only knows about binary data, it has no concept of text. If you want encrypted data to be in a textual format, you need to *encode* the encrypted binary yourself, such as a hex string, or a base64 string (which is what your `UkV8ecEWh+b1Dz0ZdwMzFVFieCI5Ps3fxYrfqAoPmOY=` example is).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice tip! I could research and find a nice solution for my case. I Appreciate the help!

Comment: @PaulSanders Nice tip! I could research and find a nice solution for my case. I Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

All Right. Thanks for the tips @RemyLebeau and @PaulSanders !!
I could resolve the issue using another tip from here -->
[Base64 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180947/base64-decode-snippet-in-c)

Working REALLY fine now!!

Thanks Much!!

Here is the code for "encode" and "decode" Base64, just in case someone wants to do the same. Very usefull!!

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
static const string b = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

static string base64_encode(const string &in) {
    string out;

    int val=0, valb=-6;
    for (uchar c : in) {
        val = (val<<8) + c;
        valb += 8;
        while (valb>=0) {
            out.push_back(b[(val>>valb)&0x3F]);
            valb-=6;
        }
    }
    if (valb>-6) out.push_back(b[((val<<8)>>(valb+8))&0x3F]);
    while (out.size()%4) out.push_back('=');
    return out;
}

static string base64_decode(const string &in) {

    string out;

    vector<int> T(256,-1);
    for (int i=0; i<64; i++) T[b[i]] = i;

    int val=0, valb=-8;
    for (uchar c : in) {
        if (T[c] == -1) break;
        val = (val<<6) + T[c];
        valb += 6;
        if (valb>=0) {
            out.push_back(char((val>>valb)&0xFF));
            valb-=8;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```